Why is my Wagner Flexio paint sprayer not working?
After a mishap with the paint hopper, a small amount of paint dripped into the blower portion of my Wagner Flexio paint sprayer and it stopped functioning. Is this thing dead now, or is there a way to clean it and revive it? I’m hesitant to replace it or exchange it if this is going to be a recurring issue. What upgrade should I consider as a replacement in the event this poor machine is gone?

what is preventing you from cleaning it? ... you answered your title question yourself

I suppose a more appropriate title question should be “Is this paint sprayer ruined?” The paint dripped into the interior of the motor and the only way I can see to clean it is by disassembling the sprayer and cleaning the individual parts. The amount of effort and skill that would require would not be worth it imo if the motor will no longer function regardless of how thorough I clean the parts…

are you saying that the motor stopped? ... you should have said that in your post
